# Contenido del ViewPager desaparece cuando navego desde mi BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, tab

Estoy trabajando con un BottomNavigationView como menu inferior y luego dentro de la vista de uno de esos menu visualizo tabs que los cree con ViewPager y un SlidingTabLayout. Mi problema en especifico es que la primera vez que entro a visualizar el contenido lo veo bien y puedo cambiar de tabs sin problema, ahora cuando cambio desde el BottomNavigationView y vuelvo mi ViewPager no tiene contenido.

Esta es la clase Java del Fragment 1 de mi BottomNavigationView donde tengo los tab que no funcionan

```
public class MyProfile extends Fragment {

   View root;
   private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
   private ViewPager mViewPager;
   private final static Fragment fProfile = new TabProfileFragment();
   private final static Fragment fMyProgress = new TabMyProgressFragment();

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_profile, container, false);

       try {

           mViewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_profile);
           mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyProfile.SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
           mSlidingTabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs_profile);
           mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);
           mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(position -> Color.WHITE);

           // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
           mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
           mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);


       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return root;
   }

   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

       @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
       private Map<Integer, Fragment> mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();

       public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
           super(fm);
       }


       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           Fragment fragment;
           Bundle args = new Bundle();

           switch(position){
               case 0:
                   fragment = fProfile;
                   break;
               case 1:
                   fragment = fMyProgress;
                   break;
               default:
                   fragment = new Fragment();
                   break;
           }

           if (fragment.getArguments() == null) {
               fragment.setArguments(args);
           }
           else {
               //Consider explicitly clearing arguments here
               fragment.getArguments().putAll(args);
           }

           mPageReferenceMap.put(position, fragment);
           return fragment;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return 2;
       }

       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           switch(position){
               case 0:
                   return getString(R.string.profile);
               case 1:
                   return getString(R.string.my_progress);
               default:
                   return  "";
           }

       }

       public Fragment getFragment(int key) {
           return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
       }

   }
}
```

Aqui su XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MyProfile.MyProfile">

    <com.doyou.brawl.utils.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_700"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Ejemplo visual de lo que estoy tratando de hacer funcionar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quiero seguir pegando codigo que no se si es necesario, pero el BottomNavigationView esta casi identico a como te lo importa cuando usas la la creacion del activity con esa plantilla. Si lo necesitan lo agrego a la pregunta no tengo problema. La verdad estuve googleando como loco pero nadie me da una solucion precisa y las cosas que intente hasta ahora no han funcionado. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pega esto en el onCreateView para que vuelva a cargar los Fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .remove(fProfile)
                     .remove(fMyProgress)
                     .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```